# How to setup a project and break it into sub-projects, how to use slick in this setup

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, slick

This is a brand new project, so I can use the latest version of play.
I am using IntelliJ 13.

So I want to break the models/db/service layer because I will also have a job service (reading messages off a queue for example) that will need this server layer also.

Since slick is outside of play, how do I setup the datasource for this project, keeping in mind I will be connecting to multiple databases.
Do I need to create a custom config file for this?

```
web-app (play2!)
 - service

service (models + dao)
models
dao

jobs (service)
```

I don't see any examples like this, which I find strange because I think pretty much any project would have to be setup this way in the real world (beyond simple examples).

Can someone show be sample code where things are broken down like this?

Answer (score 0):

This example isn't broken into sub-projects, but it is very split up and would allow you to specify multiple databases. 
https://github.com/geigerma/play-cake